# Ubuntu 12.10 not reading wifi connections on macbook pro

Tags: 12.10, wireless, drivers, macbook-pro

I installed Ubuntu onto my Mac (not dual-boot) so Mountain Lion is gone. Everything is working except for one thing, the WiFi. I tried all of the commands suggested but they don't work. I added the connections to edit connections, but they still don't pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting your Mac to Ethernet and see whether it will detect and download required drivers.

Check also **Additional Drivers** and see if it got detected already but needs to be activated.

Check this Link as well https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro